# ReportViewer - setting default filename

Tags: printing, reportviewer, xps, localreport

When I use `ReportViewer` technology (LocalReport) to print out resource from my computer using `Microsoft XPS printer`, it gives me default filename as:  `*.xps`

I would change it programmatically, how can I?

I've changed two properties:

```
        _reportViewer.LocalReport.DisplayName = _printFileName;
        _reportViewer.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = _printFileName;
```

It seems that most of technologies can understand what I want. (CutePDF, other printers), but not Microsoft XPS writer. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you are missing is one additional line:

```
_reportViewer.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;
```

Comment: thanks for answering but that did not fix it. It's still showing *.xps.